# Change TXT value with a switch button

Tags: php, html, database, txt

I wanted to know how I should go about editing my database.txt thanks to switch buttons. I'm just starting out and I'd love to understand how to get there.

**database.txt**

```
1|on|on|on|;
```

**setting.php**

```
<?php

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="switcha">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>

if (isset($_POST['switcha'])) {

}

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="switchb">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>

if (isset($_POST['switchb'])) {

}


<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="switchc">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>

if (isset($_POST['switchc'])) {

}

?>
```

This is to make redirects put on/off to enable or disable pages

**redirection.php**

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents("database.txt");
$rows = explode("|", $data);

$redirectiona = $rows[1];
$redirectionb = $rows[2];
$redirectionc = $rows[3];
    
if($redirectiona == "on"){
        header('location: 1.php');
        exit();
    }
if($redirectionb == "on"){
        header('location: 2.php');
        exit();    
    }
if($redirectionc == "on"){
        header('location: 3.php');
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Start with the same thing you are doing in your redirect script - read the data, and explode it, to create an array. Then manipulate the correct array element, use implode to turn it into a string again, and write it back to the file ...

Answer (score 0):

I have tried several times in different ways and I cannot say that if it is not enabled the value is "off" if enabled value "on". I'm sorry it may seem easy but I'm starting.

```
if (isset($_POST['switcha'])) {
    $data = file_get_contents("database.txt");
    $rows = explode("|", $data);

    $redirectiona = $rows[1];
    $redirectionb = $rows[2];
    $redirectionc = $rows[3];

    $content = str_replace("1|on|$redirectionb|$redirectionc|",file_get_contents($data));
    saveTxt($data,$content,'w');


}
```